"SQL Statement ignored" and "PLS-00201: identifier 'A.ACCID' must be declared" Errors
create or replace procedure list_job_applications(v_job_id NUMBER)
IS  
cursor c1 is select v_job_id
from accounts a, job_app ja, job_seekser js, skill s, job_seeker_skills jss
where a.accid = js.accid and a.accid = ja.accid and ja.accid = jss.accid and jss.sid = s.sid;
v_count int;
begin
select count(*) into v_count from job_posts where job_id =v_job_id;
if v_count = 0 then
dbms_output.put_line('Invalid job post ID');
 else
for item in c1 loop
        dbms.out.put_line('Account ID: ' || a.accid);
        dbms.out.put_line('Name: ' || a.acc_holder_name);
        dbms.out.put_line('Application Date: ' || TO_CHAR(a.application_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
        dbms.out.put_line('Highest Degree: ' || js.highest_degree);
        dbms.out.put_line('Work Experience (Years): ' || js.years_exp);
        dbms.out.put_line('Skill: ' || sskill_name || ', Level: ' || jss.skill_level);
end loop;
end if;
end;
/

I am currently working on a problem that list all applications to a particular job post where the input is a job post ID. The objective is to check whether or not the input is valid and if it is it will list items such as the job, account ID, name, application date, highest degree, number of years work experience, name of skill and skill levels of each applicant.
Currently I am getting errors such as:
3/14      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/46      PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
13/13     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
13/49     PLS-00201: identifier 'ACCID' must be declared
14/13     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
14/43     PLS-00201: identifier 'A.ACC_HOLDER_NAME' must be declared
15/13     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
15/63     PLS-00201: identifier 'A.APPLICATION_DATE' must be declared
16/13     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
16/53     PLS-00201: identifier 'JS.HIGHEST_DEGREE' must be declared
17/13     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
17/62     PLS-00201: identifier 'JS.YEARS_EXP' must be declared
18/13     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
18/44     PLS-00201: identifier 'SSKILL_NAME' must be declared


select IS  v_job_id?

If you edit the question and the error is different, then (1) paste the text of the error into the question (not a picture) and (2) remove the picture of the old error.

Thank you for reminding me to do that! I have just edited the question to fit my current question.

Dude, not pictures of errors. Copy the error text and paste it as text. Then press the " button to format it correctly.

Sorry, I don't know if I understood the premise correctly, but I think you might want to do something like the following, keeping in mind that I don't know the fields in each table.
Mainly, I have added the v_job_id input parameter to the WHERE of the cursor, although I do not know which of the tables it belongs to to compare it, and I have modified the fields and the way of accessing the cursor to display the information (the problem you have!).
create or replace procedure list_job_applications(v_job_id in NUMBER)
IS  
cursor c1 is select a.accid, a.acc_holder_name, a.application_date, js.highest_degree, js.years_exp, s.skill_name, jss.skill_level -- v_job_id
from accounts a, job_app ja, job_seekser js, skill s, job_seeker_skills jss
where a.accid = js.accid and a.accid = ja.accid and ja.accid = jss.accid and jss.sid = s.sid and job_id = v_job_id;
v_count int;
begin
select count(1) into v_count from job_posts where job_id = v_job_id;
if v_count = 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('Invalid job post ID');
else
for item in c1 loop
        dbms.out.put_line('Account ID: ' || item.accid);
        dbms.out.put_line('Name: ' || item.acc_holder_name);
        dbms.out.put_line('Application Date: ' || TO_CHAR(item.application_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
        dbms.out.put_line('Highest Degree: ' || item.highest_degree);
        dbms.out.put_line('Work Experience (Years): ' || item.years_exp);
        dbms.out.put_line('Skill: ' || item.skill_name || ', Level: ' || item.skill_level);
end loop;
end if;
end;

Hope this can help you

The first problem is that you're trying to run that code in schema that doesn't contain, nor has access, to some tables used.
Believe or not, I don't have your tables either, so - when I run it - this is what I get:
SQL> create or replace procedure list_job_applications(v_job_id NUMBER)
  2  IS
  3  cursor c1 is select v_job_id
  4  from accounts a, job_app ja, job_seekser js, skill s, job_seeker_skills jss
  5  where a.accid = js.accid and a.accid = ja.accid and ja.accid = jss.accid and jss.sid = s.sid;
  6  v_count int;
  7  begin
  8  select count(*) into v_count from job_posts where job_id =v_job_id;
  9  if v_count = 0 then
 10  dbms_output.put_line('Invalid job post ID');
 11   else
 12  for item in c1 loop
 13          dbms.out.put_line('Account ID: ' || a.accid);
 14          dbms.out.put_line('Name: ' || a.acc_holder_name);
 15          dbms.out.put_line('Application Date: ' || TO_CHAR(a.application_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
 16          dbms.out.put_line('Highest Degree: ' || js.highest_degree);
 17          dbms.out.put_line('Work Experience (Years): ' || js.years_exp);
 18          dbms.out.put_line('Skill: ' || sskill_name || ', Level: ' || jss.skill_level);
 19  end loop;
 20  end if;
 21  end;
 22  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

What's wrong with it?
SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE LIST_JOB_APPLICATIONS:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/14     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/55     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
8/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
8/35     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
13/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
13/47    PLS-00302: component 'ACCID' must be declared
<snip>

See? Exactly the same errors.
Oracle points to exact places where they happened, so let's take a look at a few of them.

4/55     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

It means that you should look at line #4, column #55, which is here:
from accounts a, job_app ja, job_seekser js, skill s, job_seeker_skills jss
                                                      ^
                                                      |
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
         10        20        30        40        50   55

It means that table JOB_SEEKER_SKILLS - as I said - doesn't exist in your schema, or - if it is owned by someone else - you don't have privileges to access it. As you didn't use any prefix (which would then represent owner), that might be a synonym (public or private). Additionally, note that privileges acquired via roles don't work in named stored procedures - you have to grant privileges directly to grantee.
Similarly, other table doesn't exist errors mean the same.

Then,

13/47    PLS-00302: component 'ACCID' must be declared

is related to
 12  for item in c1 loop
 13          dbms.out.put_line('Account ID: ' || a.accid);

means that you can't use table alias (or name) when referencing accid; cursor record is called item, which means that it should've been
 13          dbms.out.put_line('Account ID: ' || item.accid);

